# Twitter-Bootstrap 3.3.7- Getting Started

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, pingendo

I'm stumped. I cannot understand the getbootstrap.com Getting Started info. I'm running on Windows 7 Pro. I would like to use Pingendo - which I'm new to - to create my website.

I downloaded the distribution version bootstrap-3.3.7-dist.zip (pre-compiled) and unzipped it. Then I came to the MaxCDN code. Where do I put that code??

For the source code version, I see references to things I don't know about: Bower, npm, Composer, Grunt, Less, and SASS. All these appear to be Linux based tools - from the command lines shown. How does one accomplish the same thing under Windows without installing yet more tools? Do I even need to compile this code to use the greater features?

Answer (score 0):

You can either add the downloaded bootstrap css and js files to your project and reference them or you can just use the cdn which is just the same files hosted on a server. You do now have to know about any of those to get started with Bootstrap. They are just additional ways to install it, and different preprocessors that you can leverage.

Comment: Your answer refers to the pre-compiled distribution. Supposedly it has much fewer features. Are you saying that I just need to download the source code and use it without compiling it?

Comment: Just download the one that says Bootstrap Compiled and minified CSS, JavaScript and fonts. It will have a .js and a .css file, place those in your projects main js and css folder respectively. After that is done reference that js and css in any html page you want to use Bootsrap. Alternatively you can just add the cdn's to your html. Those CDN's are under the Bootstrap CDN section of this page http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download . You can also use the Source Code or Sass version but those require compilers to turn the less or sass to css.

Comment: OK, will copy the Bootstrap CDN html code from the getting started page, into the header of the Basic Template. So no need to download the CSS, JS and font folders. How do I know that I'm actually using Bootstrap and MaxCDN - I mean from the Pingendo UI? What should I see to convince me?

Comment: You can tell that you are have bootstrap added to the project correctly because you will then be able to use bootstrap classes on your page elements. For example you can wrap your body content in a <div class="container"></div> This will add margin to the left and right and make the page more responsivie. You can also use stuff like the bootstrap grid which basically allows you to specify element size depending on screen size. Here is an example I made for you on codepen: http://codepen.io/CodeBroJohn/pen/QKwozw

Comment: I looked at the codepen example. I used it under Pingendo and there was, of course, no other sections or components available for drag and drop use. That's the problem. I'll have to look at Pingendo themes and see if that helps.

Comment: I changed from Pingendo Beta 4 to the proper V4 release and components improved in type and number. Nothing yet done explicitly with bootstrap although the default Pingendo theme (on line) may use Bootstrap. I think its time to begin a thread on Pingendo.

Comment: I gave Pingendo a look and if you use it, whatever you build will include bootstrap. All of those components and sections they allow you to drag and drop are bootstrap components. Given that they are Bootstrap components your page will automatically adapt to fit various screen sizes. If you look at the actual HTML of the page you build with Pingendo you will see that it uses some of those bootstrap classes I mentioned earlier. For instance this is the css for bootstrap in a pingendo sample <link href="http://v4.pingendo.com/assets/bootstrap/themes/purple.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

Comment: You can see the javascript for it as well before the end of the body. Exactly what bootstrap components are you trying to use that are not avaliable to be dragged and dropped? If there are some not there you should be able to just write them in by editing the HTML code.

Comment: Just a tip a lot of your questions are getting voted down because they are not very direct and consise, that is one reason not many people are helping. I do not mind helping because I know sometimes as a begineer it is hard to articulate your questions. However, if you continue to create new threads and expect my help, please mark my answers as the correct answer when that is the case. Otherwise me helping you out does not benifit myself nor the community at large.